# VS Code - Debugger Won't Step Into Function

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm following a tutorial using VS Code in which, in the learning material, the instructor sets a debugger on the first of the following 2 lines and then steps into the `require` function to see how the Node library handles importing files:

```
var greet = require('./greet');
greet();
```

In this simple example, `greet` is just a simple function in `greet.js` that logs *Hi* to the console. The function is then exported.

In the tutorial video I'm watching, the instructor sets a breakpoint on line 1, fires up the debugger and when the breakpoint is hit (indicated by yellow highlight) selects "Step Into" control. In the video, the debugger steps into the `require` function to see what Node is doing - cool!

When I do the same, starting the debugger works as expected and the relevant line with its various entities highlights yellow:

[image: Start debugger]

The first click of "Step into" does nothing AFAICT. The second click then steps into the `greet` function, rather than `require`.

I'm guessing that something in Code's behaviour has changed since the video I'm using was recorded. I note that the breakpoint location displayed in the bottom-left panel shows a line and column number `1:1` but I can't seem to overwrite this value and have it step into the `require` function I'm interested in.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. For me it worked to uninstall the version I was using (20.2.0) and install the LTS version of Node(18.16.0).